# How can I create custom accents?

Tags: accents, number

I need to make number accents above and below like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have the `accents` package at your disposal.

Comment: @Bernard Unfortunately the accents package really only works well with italicized characters. With Roman characters the "accents" aren't always centered.

Answer (score 10):

You need a scalable font, so for Computer Modern I use `fix-cm` and the T1 encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numabove}[2]{% #1 = number, #2 = letter
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \fontsize{0.3\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{0}\selectfont #1\cr
      \noalign{\vskip 0.4pt}
      #2\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\numbelow}[2]{% #1 = number, #2 = letter
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      #2\cr
      \noalign{\vskip 0.4pt}
      \fontsize{0.3\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{0}\selectfont #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\numbelow{2}{T}
\numabove{6}{t}
\numbelow{8}{A}
\numbelow{5}{a}
\numabove{7}{E}
\numabove{2}{e}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This won't really work well with italic, some adjustment could be made in case you need it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numabove}[2]{% #1 = number, #2 = letter
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt
        % the font is slanted
        \sbox\z@{#2}%
        \kern\strip@pt\fontdimen1\font\dimexpr\wd\z@*2\relax
      \fi
      {\fontsize{0.3\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{0}\selectfont #1}\cr
      \noalign{\vskip 0.4pt}
      #2\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\numbelow}[2]{% #1 = number, #2 = letter
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      #2\cr
      \noalign{\vskip 0.4pt}
      {\fontsize{0.3\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{0}\selectfont #1}%
      \ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt
        % the font is slanted
        \sbox\z@{#2}%
        \kern\strip@pt\fontdimen1\font\dimexpr\wd\z@/2\relax
      \fi\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\numbelow{2}{T}
\numabove{6}{t}
\numbelow{8}{A}
\numbelow{5}{a}
\numabove{7}{E}
\numabove{2}{e}

\textit{\numbelow{2}{T}
\numabove{6}{t}
\numbelow{8}{A}
\numbelow{5}{a}
\numabove{7}{E}
\numabove{2}{e}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can define macros `\accentabove` and `\accentbelow`:

```
\font\fiverm=cmr5

\def\accentabove#1#2{\leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
     \halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\fiverm #2\cr\noalign{\kern.2ex}#1\cr}}%
}
\def\accentbelow#1#2{\leavevmode
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip
     \halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr#1\cr\noalign{\kern.2ex}\fiverm #2\cr}}%
}

%test:

\accentabove t6, \accentbelow T6

\bye
```

Answer (score 6):

A `stackengine` solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\aup}[2]{\Shortstack[c]{{\tiny #2} {#1}}}
\newcommand{\adn}[2]{\Shortunderstack[c]{{#1} {\tiny #2}}}
\begin{document}
   Text \aup{T}{2}\adn{t}{6} more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

(you can tweak spacing to your taste, see the [`stackengine` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/stackengine/0))

PS: notice that if the two elements are single tokens, you can avoid the braces, although that is not really LaTeX-ish...

```
 More text \aup T2 \adn t6 more text
```

Adding, as [suggested by @frabjous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636853/how-to-create-custom-accents/636860#comment1587094_636860), `\setstackgap{S}{1px}`, you have:

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution. I'd recommend throwing in something like `\setstackgap{S}{1px}` to reduce the vertical space between the letters and the "accents".